# If text value is higher or higher then x

Tags: jquery, html

What I am trying to do is if a value of a span is higher then a certain value it logs if it is higher or lower in console, I want to do this with 3 values but it is only letting me do the top two. below is my code.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var raitingTotal = $(".total-score span").text();
    if (raitingTotal >= 7) {
        console.log('higher than 7');
    }
    if (raitingTotal <= 6.9) {
        console.log('lower than 7');
    }
    if (raitingTotal >= 3.5) {
        console.log('higher than or equal to 3.5');
    }

});
```

Comment: What are you actually getting in the console? For a number between 3.5 and 6.9 it should log "lower than 7" AND "higher than or equal to 3.5". Are you not getting that?

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W2Z7P/ Everything seems to be working with no changes. Please further describe your problem.

Comment: if (raitingTotal >= 3.5)  is supposed to be if (raitingTotal <= 3.5, now i do a value of 3.4 and it outputs both 'lower than 7' and 'higher than or equal to 3.5'

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parseFloat in order to convert from string into a number.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var raitingTotal = parseFloat($(".total-score span").text());
    if (raitingTotal >= 7) {
        console.log('higher than 7');
    }
    if (raitingTotal <= 6.9) {
        console.log('lower than 7');
    }
    if (raitingTotal >= 3.5) {
        console.log('higher than or equal to 3.5');
    }
});
```

Comment: small explanation of parseFloat might be handy for op

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat Dont know why W3 schools is always the first result...MDN is a good source

Comment: I am researching now!

Comment: parseFloat is unnecessary as the string is coerced to a number implicitly by the >= and <= operators. That is not the problem.